# With an Azure Web App, is it possible to monitor costs incurred grouped by URL GET parameters?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-webapps

If I create an Azure Web App service running some sort of web application (In my case a R-Shiny web app), is it possible to monitor the costs of the Web App per HTTP Get request parameter?

For example, if my app runs at myshinyapp.azurewebsites.net, is there a way to get a cost analysis grouped by HTTP GET request parameters, such that I monitor the **total costs** incurred separately for each of the following:

- myshinyapp.azurewebsites.net/?tab=1
- myshinyapp.azurewebsites.net/?tab=2
- myshinyapp.azurewebsites.net/?tab=3

I would not be adverse to running any additional service such as Azure App Insights, or API Monitor if required to get this breakdown, but is it possible?

Comment: Cost for Azure WebApps is not based on the number of requests so I don't think you can get this information. What you could possibly do is get the total requests and calculate the pro-rated cost of each type of request. But this will not be accurate by any means as you're paying for the WebApp even if there are no requests being made.

Comment: Thanks! I understand. 

Just to be clear though, I'm more interested in the resource usage related costs than the number of requests to each.

Each of those requests call separate R modules that are each fairly CPU hungry. So I'm trying to see what each request costs me in CPU usage regardless of the number of times they have been called.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for explaining. You should be able to get this information from App Insights logs (IIS Logs to be precise).